# Data packages? (cities, sports teams etc)

Tags: list, web, collections

I am working on a project that could use a list of every city, region, country in the world. Countless websites use the same data so I think there must be some data packages containing such lists (of sports teams, of politicians etc.) somewhere on the internet.

Could you tell me what they are called? Are there any websites/sources that you would recommend? What about pictures, can I find similar resources for pictures or icons?

Comment: http://www.geonames.org/

Comment: Thank you. So, this website gives me a zip file, how exactly do I use it?

Also, are there similar sources for, say, sports teams? Do I need to try to find everything separately?

Comment: I still need help, anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Some of what you may need can be found on http://data.okfn.org/data/ - e.g. list of countries, cities, regions etc.